# Database pair of tens of millions of data optimal storage solution

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a messages table, my current message can be assigned to some people to view, so I thought of using two tables to achieve this function, the following is my main message table:

```
create table tbMessages (
    `iMessageId` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
        `sContent` varchar(1000) not null default '',
    `dtCommitTime` datetime not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    primary key `pk_iMessageId` (`iMessageId`)
)engine=innodb default charset=utf8mb4;
```

I need to set the specified person to view the message, so I designed a tbMessages table to represent the relationship between the user and the message. Below is my tbUserMessages table:

```
create table tbUserMessages (
    `iSeqId` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `iUserId` int unsigned not null default 0 comment 'user id',
    `iMessageId` int unsigned not null default 0,
    `dtCommitTime` datetime not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    primary key `pk_iSeqId` (`iSeqId`)
)engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

Then, I found that every time I create or say that I push a message, I need to insert n records into the tbUserMessages table. Since it is possible to select multiple user teams in batches, this may occur. Each message is created and will be additionally written. Entering 100 million pieces of data into the tbUserMessages table, the maintenance cost is too expensive, and once I delete the message, I need to delete all the records in the table. This will cause the card to be stuck. Is there any other better design?

Comment: What is difference between create and push message?

Comment: Your design looks OK for me. Except one little detail. It seems like foreign key constraints on `tbUserMessages` are missing. You can even define them with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so that records get automatically delete if a message or a user gets deleted. To increase performance of `DELETE`s and `SELECT`s check for proper indexes.

Comment: @skelwa Yes, they are the same meaning.

Comment: @stickybit Thank you.